# How to set an option in Highchart inactive by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this code here from this page: http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo

```
$(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Combination chart'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Bananas', 'Plums']
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    var s;
                    if (this.point.name) { // the pie chart
                        s = ''+
                            this.point.name +': '+ this.y +' fruits';
                    } else {
                        s = ''+
                            this.x  +': '+ this.y;
                    }
                    return s;
                }
            },
            labels: {
                items: [{
                    html: 'Total fruit consumption',
                    style: {
                        left: '40px',
                        top: '8px',
                        color: 'black'
                    }
                }]
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [3, 2, 1, 3, 4]
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'John',
                data: [2, 3, 5, 7, 6]
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0]
            }, {
                type: 'spline',
                name: 'Average',
                data: [3, 2.67, 3, 6.33, 3.33],
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fillColor: 'white'
                }
            }, {
                type: 'pie',
                name: 'Total consumption',
                data: [{
                    name: 'Jane',
                    y: 13,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0] // Jane's color
                }, {
                    name: 'John',
                    y: 23,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1] // John's color
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    y: 19,
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[2] // Joe's color
                }],
                center: [100, 80],
                size: 100,
                showInLegend: false,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

And it produces this statistic here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo/

I would like to be able to set "John" and "Joe" inactive by default. Is there a way to make this? It should be possible to activate them though.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by inactive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to initially draw in an "invisible" state?

```
        {
            type: 'column',
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [4, 3, 3, 9, 0],
            visible: false // <-- set visibility to false
        },
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Dh74w/).